# Blocked access to a route item if the user is not assigned

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to block a route where the logged-on user's ID is not the same as the route of the object he's trying to edit.

Example :

*I am in charge of administering different buildings assigned to me with the key "user_id" in the database (in the building table). I am demonic and I want to go change the sheet of a building that I do not mind. By taking the URL, I can go to modify the building of my enemy.*

I create a relation in my model `Building`

```
  public function owner()
  {
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
  }
```

And a middleware

```
use App\Models\Building;
use Closure;
use Auth;

class CheckOwnItem
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ( Auth::id() != Building::class->user_id){
          abort(403);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

When I want to access my route with the middleware 'building', I have an error. I think that I don't access correctly the data of my buildings. How to do ?

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)
```

Thank you !

Comment: `Building::class` is a string type, not object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve a building instance and then do the checking.

Something like this maybe:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $building = Building::find($request->id);

    if ( Auth::id() != $building->user_id){
      abort(403);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```